# react express database request

Tags: reactjs, express

I am newbie at both expressjs and reactjs. Trying to learn for a new job which will require connection to a Database

I was learning by trying a couple of examples online.

I've installed an express generator skeleton and trying out a couple of demos but I am having problems rendering anything on the app page. In this case iterating through a list of data, or when I look in the network tab, I dont see a response from the database end point I am trying to hit. I am also having problems trying to debug in node express, I find the errors not helpful (unexpected token at line xxx). Is there a better way to debug? console log and alerting doesnt seem to be working.

Can someone take a look at my code, and see if I am doing something wrong? I'm getting an error on the input lines and also when I remove it, I dont see the request from the endpoint or any output from my code.

My routes/index.js file: 
I am getting results when I hit these pages (products and products/add):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password: 'root',
    port: 8889, 
    database: 'react-db'
})

connection.connect(err => {
    if(err){
        return err;
    }
})

const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM products'

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/products', function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err,results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            return res.json({
                data:results
            })
        }
    })
});

router.get('/products/add', function(req, res, next) {
    const {name, price} = req.query;
    const INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY = `INSERT INTO products (name,price) VALUES('${name}', ${price})`
    connection.query(INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err,results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send('adding product')
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting an error on the input tag lines but also when I remove them, I dont see the output from the products list. If the database connection is failing, its not outputting to the console.log:

```
var React = require('react');

class Products extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            product: {
                name:"sample product",
                price: 0
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getProducts();
        alert(0)
    }

    getProducts(){
        fetch("./products")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({products: data}))      
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    addProduct(){
        const {product} = this.state;
        fetch("./products/add?name=${product.name}&price=${products.price}")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(this.getProducts)
        .catch(err=> console.error(err))
    }

    render() {
        const { products, product } = this.state;

        return (
            <div> 
             { 
               products.map(function (product, index) {
                 return <div key={product.product_id}>{product.name}</div>
               })
             }
           <div>
               <input value={product.name}
                      onChange={e => this.setState({product: {...product, name: e.target.value}})}/>
               <input value={product.price}
                      onChange={e => this.setState({product: {...product, price: e.target.value}})}/>
               <button onClick={this.addProduct}>Add Product</button>
           </div>
           <button onClick={this.addProduct}>Add Product</button>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

module.exports = Products;
```

Comment: `.then(this.getProducts)` should be   `.then(() => this.getProducts())`

Answer (score 0):

There are few things:

1 - when you are using a inner method of a component, you should bind it to `this` in the constructor

2 - your API will certainly run on a specific `IP:PORT`, let say  `localhost:8000`

So try updating your code like this:

```
class Products extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            product: {
                name:"sample product",
                price: 0
            }
        }

        this.getProducts = this.getProducts.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {   
        try {
            const data = await this.getProducts();
            this.setState({products: data}
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    getProducts(){
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/products")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data)      
        .catch(err => err)
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your help.  I tried your example but still get no results from the products table even though the end point is working for /products.  I dont know how to debug in this application. I tried debugger, console.log and nothing seems to work.  Pls advise?